# Delay android requesting permissions

Tags: android

I have an app which contains `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>`

Is there a way to delay asking the user for the location permission until they take an account which requires it? I've tried removing uses-permission from the XML, this breaks location even after programmatically asking for location permissions.

I do programmatically ask for location info, but that only seems to work if the permission is also specified in the XML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming that you are experiencing this as you're targeting below Android 6.0?

[As per the docs](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/usage-notes)

> Android 6.0 Marshmallow introduced a new permissions model that lets
> apps request permissions from the user at runtime, rather than prior
> to installation. Apps that support the new model request permissions
> when the app actually requires the services or data protected by the
> services.

Therefore, you will be unable to avoid requesting permissions before the user actually needs to use that particular service, unless you target a higher API level.

Comment: I'm using the QT framework and found that it makes this request automatically when the GPS is first requested. Thanks for your answer it got me looking int he right direction.

Answer (score 1):

If you need permission, you can not remove it from manifest. If your target API is above 23 (Android 6) Just ask for permission programmatically when you need it. You as developer determine when to ask for permissions.

Otherwise if user's device is below android 6 or if your target API is below 23 then permissions will be requested at install time and you can not change it.